# Pass Context from JUnit Runner to Cucumber Steps

Tags: android, ios, junit, appium, cucumber-junit

I use Cucumber with a JUnit runner. I do App UI Tests with Appium, but that should not matter for this question. The relevant part is that I want to reuse features and step definitions across iOS and Android, and **pass the selenium driver instance from JUnit to the steps**, as I only want to start the test server once.

I have something like this:

`login.feature`:

```
Feature: Login
@android_phone @ios_phone
Scenario: Successful login
    Given ...
```

`CucumberIOSTest.java`:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = {"classpath:my.stepdefinitions"},
        tags = {"@ios_phone,@ios_tablet"}
)
public class CucumberIOSTest {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        // setup code that starts up the ios simulator via appium 
        driver = DriverFactory.createIOSDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        // shutdown ios simulator
    }

}
```

And nearly the same for Android in `CucumberAndroidTest.java`:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = {"classpath:my.stepdefinitions"},
        tags = {"@android_phone,@android_tablet"}
)
public class CucumberAndroidTest {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        // setup code that starts up the android simulator via appium 
        driver = DriverFactory.createAndroidDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        // shutdown android simulator
    }

}
```

The steps are located in `GenericSteps.java` (for now just one file):

```
public class GenericSteps {
    public GenericSteps(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @Given("^...$")
    public void ...() throws Throwable {
        ...
    }
}
```

**How can I pass the `driver` from `CucumberIOSTest`/`CucumberAndroidTest` to the Steps constructor?**

The problem is that only the `CucumberIOSTest`/`CucumberAndroidTest` instance knows whether I want to test the iOS or Android tags. The `GenericSteps` cannot know this. Also I only want to start the simulator once for all tests on each platform respectively.

I tried DI, but I did not find a way to pass the `WebDriver` instance I created in the JUnit Runner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simplest solution is use [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.
DriverFactory have to always return the same instance of WebDriver. So inside your DriverFactory add 'static WebDriver instance' and getWebDriver() method.

```
public final class DriverFactory {
  private static WebDriver instance = null;

  public static synchronized WebDriver getWebDriver() {
      if (instance == null) {throw RuntimeException("create WebDriver first")};
      return instance;
  }
  public static synchronized WebDriver createAndroidDriver() {
      if (instance == null) { 
         // setup code that starts up the android simulator via appium 
         instance  = yourWebDriver
      }
      return instance;
  }
  ...
}
```

now your GenericSteps cal look like this:

```
public class GenericSteps {
  public GenericSteps() {
      this.driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
  }

  @Given("^...$")
  public void ...() throws Throwable {
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, that actually works, thanks! I just need to reset the WebDriver instance in `@AfterClass` too, so it works correctly when I first run the iOS tests and then the Android tests.